# Which is the better way for implement a repository in ddd (Golang example)?

Tags: go, repository, domain-driven-design

I want to find a good way to implement repository pattern in Go, but there are some problems:

1. For list filter, I need to write lot's of methods in repository, or use a query object and write many if ... else ... in method.
2. If I use an db function as parameter in repository, My domain layer will depends on `sql.DB` or an ORM and I don't like that.

Any advise or more beautiful implementation?

use query object, my repository may like:

```golang
type IUsers interface {
    GetByID(ctx context.Context, userID string) (User, error)
    GetUserList(ctx context.Context) ([]User, error)
    FindUsers(ctx context.Context, qo UserQueryObject) ([]User, error)
}

type UserQueryObject struct {
    Limit         int
    Offset        int
    RoleIn        []string
    CreatedBefore time.Time
}
```

It can work will, but all conditions will in query object.

In the second way, it may like:

```golang
type SC func(*gorm.DB) *gorm.DB

type IUsers interface {
    FindOne(context.Context, ...SC) (User, error)
    FindAll(context.Context, ...SC) ([]User, error)
}

func WithLimit(limit int) SC {
    return func(d *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
        return d.Limit(limit)
    }
}
```

but I need import `gorm.DB` in my domain layer.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely the first option, but I'd call the methods `GetUser` and `ListUsers` or `GetAllUsers`. For the `Find`-ing case, consider what clauses that are needed for the business case -- there may be fewer than you think at first, and if there are no interactions between them (AND/ORs), they could even become top level "FindByX" methods, especially if some of the subclauses are only used to further narrow down the primary results (e.g., "FindUsersByRole", optionally filtered by their creation date). If searching has to be more general, then a `FindUsers` method with a query object looks reasonable to me.

However, I wouldn't necessarily keep limit and offset in the query object -- those are more of infra concerns, that you could attach into the context in your web API handlers and process in the SQL repo implementation if they are present. (This is probably just my personal preference, I'm actually not sure what's the generally accepted technique for this case.)

For more detail and specific code examples, I can recommend the Three Dots Labs series of articles walking through a design and refactoring of a web app using Clean Architecture principles, starting with the article ["Introducing Clean Architecture"](https://threedots.tech/post/introducing-clean-architecture/).